# Post more than 1 pictures with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

So far, I am only able to post one picture with html form into mySql table with this code:

```
$foldername="events/"; //path to save image
$con=mysql_connect("mysql.website.com","xxxxx","xxxxxx") or die("Fail");
mysql_select_db("u141416789_fin")  or die("Fail");
if (!empty($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]))
{

if($image=="image/jpeg" || $image=="image/jpg" || $image=="image/gif" || $image=="image/x-png")
{           
    $gambar = $foldername. basename($_FILES['image']['name']);       
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $gambar)) {
        echo "Gambar berhasil dikirim ".$gambar;

        $sql="INSERT INTO education (id, category, title, date, content, fullcontent, image) 
        VALUES (0, 'events', '$title', '$date', '$content', '$fullcontent', '$gambar')";
        $res=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
 } 
   else {echo "Image fail to send";}
 } 
   else {echo "Image must be .jpg .gif .png";}
 } 
   else {echo "Please choose image";}
```

*Note: There a few lines I cut from the code above such as the "$id, $category, $title, etc, becasue they are not the main problem in this question*.

I post the picture with an html form of file-field.

```
     <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
```

At that time, I only need one picture to post in the template of article.

But today, I need to post more than one picture.

Is there a simple way or another php code to do that beside the php code above so that it can help me to be able to post more than one picture?

---

---

This is my full code

```
<?php

$text = str_replace('\'', '\'\'', $text);

$namafolder="events/"; //tempat menyimpan file gambar
$tpl_path="events/";
$tpl_file = "eventstemplate.html";//nama template
$submission_path="events/";

$con=mysql_connect("mysql.idhostinger.com","u141416789_fin","alkasih") or die("Gagal");
mysql_select_db("u141416789_fin")  or die("Gagal");
if (!empty($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$content=$_POST['content'];
$fullcontent=$_POST['fullcontent']; 
$image=$_FILES['image']['type'];
if($image=="image/jpeg" || $image=="image/jpg" || $image=="image/gif" || $image=="image/x-png")
{           
    $gambar = $namafolder . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);       
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $gambar)) {
        echo "Gambar berhasil dikirim ".$gambar;

        $sql="INSERT INTO education (id, category, title, date, content, fullcontent, image) 
        VALUES (0, 'events', '$title', '$date', '$content', '$fullcontent', '$gambar')";
 $res=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
} else {echo "Gambar gagal dikirim";}
} else {echo "Jenis gambar yang anda kirim salah. Harus .jpg .gif .png";}
} else {echo "Anda belum memilih gambar";}



    $data['keywords']=$_POST['keywords'];
    $data['date']=$_POST['date'];
    $data['title']=$_POST['title'];
    $data['content']=$_POST['content'];
    $data['fullcontent']=$_POST['fullcontent'];
    $data['filename']=$_POST['filename'];


    $placeholders= array ("{keywords}", "{date}", "{title}", "{content}", "{fullcontent}", "{filename}");
    $tpl=file_get_contents($tpl_path.$tpl_file);
    $new_submission_file = str_replace($placeholders, $data, $tpl);
    $php_file_name=$title.".html";

    $fp=fopen($submission_path.$php_file_name, "w");
    fwrite($fp, $new_submission_file);
    fclose($fp);



  mysql_close($con);        
  ?>
```

Comment: Just check out the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php Here the describe how to handle it, example code and all.

Comment: Search for multiple Ajax File upload. And please use MySQLi or PDO. MySQL is deprecated!

Comment: Aaaarrgghhh **stop using the `mysql_*()` functions** - they're deprecated and _massively_ insecure. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements instead. If you care about the security of your users' data in _any_ way you should've done this a long time ago

Comment: I am sory guys, but I am very new at this. I was just trying to do this by my self (self-taught) :) Thank you for your references, all.

Comment: #Webice and #Bojangles, can you help me to change my code with PDO, please, so that I will have an idea how to do that.

Comment: @Al Kush http://de2.php.net/pdo   PDO is like mysql or mysqli. You have to learn it. Its useless if i write your code correctly in PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is only for a PDO example.

A PDO Connection. And a Try Catch Construct for Error exeptions.

```
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUser = 'root';
$dbPassword = 'password';
$dbDatabase = 'databaseName';
$dbCharset = 'UTF8';

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbHost . ';dbname=' . $dbDatabase . ';charset=' . $dbCharset . ';', $dbUser, $dbPassword);
} catch (PDOException $connectionError) {
    throw new Exception('Connection failed: ' . $connectionError->getMessage());
}
```

A simple Query with prepared Statement.

```
$thisQuery = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :columID');
$thisQuery->bindParam(':columID', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$thisQuery->execute();
$thisQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Hope it helps you a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use file upload input with the attribute "multiple"

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" multiple accept="image/*">
```

And, from PHP you can access these files as an array.

Refer below link for more details.
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php